# Switft Dictionary problem 'String?' is not convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I'm new to Swift and ObjC and can't get this simple bit of code to work. I get the error 'String?' is not convertible to 'String'; did you mean to use 'as!' to force downcast?

```
    guard let data = context as? Dictionary<String,String> else {return}

    var str : String

    str = data["Score"] as String //<<<I get the error here
```

When I change it to as! I know get this warning: Forced cast from 'String?' to 'String' only unwraps optionals; did you mean to use '!'?

Any ideas how to extract the string from the dictionary so I can use it?

Comment: You don't need to cast it but the result from doing `data["Score"]` might be null

Comment: You should understand following. Every time you get `NSString` in Objective-C - it can be nil. In Swift it depends on context. For `Dictionary` it will be `String?`. It means string can be nil. Have you read Apple's book about Swift? :)

Answer (score 5):

It might be possible, that the key "Score" is not set in your dictionary and may return nil. Use this code to unwrap the optional:

```
if let score = data["Score"] {
    str = score
}
```

Since you already unwrapped `context` to `Dictionary<String, String>`, Swift will automatically infer the type of `score` as String.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to cast because `data` dictionary would always return optional `String` type and you can use `guard` statement

```
guard let str = data[Score] else { return }
// Your code here
```

Answer (score 0):

The type returned by subscripting a `Dictionary` is an optional, since it is valid to subscript it with non-existinent keys. So, as per the error message, in a dictionary with `String` values, the return type is `String?`.

If you know for sure that the key always exist in the dictionary, you can force-unwrap it as `data["Score"]!` to make the type `String` (without casting, but crashing if it doesn't exist). Otherwise handle the `nil` in some way, e.g., `if let str = data["Score"]` or `str = data["Score"] ?? "0"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
if let dataDictionary = context as? [String: Any] {
        if let someString = dataDictionary["score"] as? String {
            print(someString)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We don't know what kind of data you're working with but you're likely either getting back a dictionary actually of type `[String: String]`, in which case you would:

```
func getData(context: [String: String]) {
    guard let str = context["Score"] else {
        return
    }
    print(str)
}
```

...or you're really getting back a dictionary of type `[String: Any]` (more common with database dictionaries), in which case you would:

```
func getData(context: [String: Any]) {
    guard let str = context["Score"] as? String else {
        return
    }
    print(str)
}
```